# MBP display, keyboard backlight and camera issue

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display, hardware, camera

I have a mid 2009 MBP which was heating up way to fast because of the fan; then I bought a new one and changed it. I also applied a new thermal grease. Plugged all the cables, tightened all the screws, reset SMC, reset NVRAM and turned on.

The heat is gone and its running perfectly now, but:

1. the display started showing some "blurry ghosts" at the bottom of the screen which won't show if I take a screenshot, so I took a photo that you can see below.

[image: ghosting]

2. the keyboard backlight isn't turning on. I tried to unplug and plug the cable over and over again, but nothing happened.
3. the camera isn't working at all. All I see is a black screen.

Is there anything I can do to fix any of these issues?

Comment: As I can't post more than 2 links, I'm posting it here. This is the [new fan](https://www.amazon.com/iParaAiluRy-Laptop-Cooling-Macbook-Unibody/dp/B00FWPGGLK/ref=sr_1_1?) and [thermal grease](https://www.amazon.com/Be-Quiet-BZ001-DC1-WAERMELEITPASTE/dp/B00BLJGLAW).

Comment: Why would you need thermal grease unless you removed the CPU heatsink, which isn't necessary?  Did you disconnect your display and your keyboard?  Again, why would you do that as it's not necessary to change a fan?   More than likely, all the 
"plugging of cables" and "tightening of screws" may have resulted in poor connections.  I would suggest making sure all your connections are correct and secure and not over tight.

Comment: As I was gonna open it, I did it all at once. Changed the fan and the thermal grease.

Comment: So thats, probably, a cable connection problem? I didn't try to unplug and plug the camera cable. But I did tried n times to do it with the display and keyboard backlight cable.

Comment: At minimum, it could be a poor connection, but you could have also caused damage.  The first thing I would do is re-seat all of your connections.

Comment: I will try to do it now. Should I clean the connections with isopropyl alcohol (99.8%), even though I've already cleaned yesterday?

Comment: Why, oh why are you doing this?  Basically, alcohol attracts water.  If you are cleaning these connectors, you should use an [electrical cleaning **solvent**](http://amzn.to/29EBYs5).  When you put everything back, are you ***certain*** those connectors are dry?

Comment: I've seen people cleaning the logic board with this alcohol, so I supposed that wasn't any problem to clean the connectors. Its dries super fast (less than I minute), but I did wait more than a minute to make sure its completely dry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42620/discussion-between-allan-and-luiz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely caused damage to your MacBook Pro's screen, video cable, and or keyboard cable.

I did a bit of research and found a very similar condition to the picture you provided (see below) it’s called “stage lighting effect”.  This was posted on the [iFixit forum](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/46098/Dim-Dark+%27spots%27+on+display).  The resolution to this problem was a warranty replacement.   Being that your MacBook Pro is 6 to 7 years old, this will be an out-of-pocket repair.

[image]

You may be able to repair it by replacing the backlight led, but at this point, it's purely speculative.  My suggestion is to replace the screen rather than risk further damage by attempting to replace the backlight.